# Torchlight transmutations

Tags: steam, torchlight

So far, I've only been able to create gems and potions.  I've found a few sites online that say you can do other stuff, but I've never been able to make it work.

Anyone have experience here?

Answer (score 5):

I don't have much experience, but I have tried a few of the combinations found [here](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Torchlight/Transmutation)
and have gotten them to work (3 rings = 1 ring, 4 rare items = medium gem)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty [complete summary](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Duran_the_Transmuter) with a table. It mentions unique items and other goodies.